# Jumping in Stream of Audio in Flask

Tags: python, flask, audio, streaming, pause

The below code streams audio

```
@app.route("/mp3")
def stream-mp3():
    def generate():
        with open("signals/my.mp3", "rb") as mp3:
            data = mp3.read(1024)
            while data:
                yield data
                data = mp3.read(1024)
    return Response(generate(), mimetype="audio/mp3")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want the user to be able to jump to different points of the audio in the browser. How should I modify this code?

Answer (score 1):

Old post i know but thought i would put something here as no replys so far...

Have you tried wavesurfer.js? you have a customizable waveform. The waveform can then be clicked on anywhere and it will jump to that part of the song/track.

This may be a bit fancy though for what you are after?